# Intersection of two paths or a path and a point never returns true

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184397/path-intersection-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588003/android-how-to-check-if-a-path-contains-touched-point) questions, all about detection intersections in Android. Well, I couldn't manage to make them work with the final code, so I made an example where 2 lines definitely intersect. Not even lucky in that case. I've made an example code with two straight paths, regions that fit them, and a point that definitely crosses it. Completely unlucky.

```
var theyCross = false
val intersectionPath = Path()

val clipArea = Region(0, 0, 100, 100)
val path1 = Path()
path1.moveTo(50f, 0f)
path1.lineTo(50f, 100f)

val path2 = Path()
path2.moveTo(0f, 50f)
path2.lineTo(100f, 50f)

val newRegion1 = Region()
newRegion1.setPath(path1, clipArea)

val newRegion2 = Region()
newRegion2.setPath(path2, clipArea)

if(
    !newRegion1.quickReject(newRegion2) && 
    newRegion1.op(newRegion2, Region.Op.INTERSECT)
) {
    // lines should cross!
    theyCross = true
}

if (intersectionPath.op(path1, path2, Path.Op.INTERSECT)) {
    if (!intersectionPath.isEmpty) {
        // lines should cross!
        theyCross = true
    }
}

if (newRegion1.contains(50, 50)) {
    // lines should cross!
    theyCross = true
}

if (newRegion1.quickContains(49, 49, 51, 51)) {
    // lines should cross!
    theyCross = true
}
```

In this example I'm not using a `Canvas`, but in my original code, I am, and each path is made of a `Paint` with `strokeWidth`. No luck. Has any of you faced this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works if the paths are surfaces, not lines, e.g. :

```
val clipArea = Region(0, 0, 100, 100)
val path1 = Path()
path1.moveTo(50f, 0f)
path1.lineTo(50f, 100f)
path1.lineTo(51f, 100f)
path1.lineTo(51f, 0f)
path1.close()

val path2 = Path()
path2.moveTo(0f, 50f)
path2.lineTo(100f, 50f)
path2.lineTo(100f, 51f)
path2.lineTo(0f, 51f)
path2.close()
```

By the way the (ignored) return value of `newRegion1.setPath(path1, clipArea)` is now true (non-empty) instead of false

Comment: That's awesome, thanks!. Now, I'll have to find a way to convert a complex, user-made path into a closed one! _I'm still wondering why one would need a region, if it is virtually useless (I honestly thought using a region was to **actually** convert a path into a surface!)_

Comment: Just as a heads up, after I tried it with complex `Path`s and a 3x3 pixels rectangle (made out of a closed `Path`), it turns out it intersects with paths as if they were closed (so, it will intersect the interior of a curve, but not the exterior!). After this, it is clear that my previous comment and your answer are **the** answer.

Comment: @Korcholis can you explain how it worked? you have example of code with complex path?

Comment: Hey @VadimEksler, I don't have the code anymore, but from what I remember, after getting the point list, I just created a copy of the list with 1 added pixel in one of the dimensions and added it in reverse to the drawing list. Something like **A, B, C, D, D(-1), C(-1), B(-1), A(-1)** . This way, you're creating a really thin closed path (of just one pixel tall or wide) which will be hard to perceive by the user (especially if the strokeWidth is more than 1 pixel). Then it's just a matter of `close()`ing the path.

Comment: @Korcholis tnx but wich method exactly works to detect intersect