# Path.op.INTERSECT with simple lines is always empty

Tags: android

I want to detect a line intersection using `Android.graphics.Path`. Right now, it seems that the intersection is always empty, even though the lines should intersect. To reproduce this, I created this simplifed code that is running within my Activity's `onCreate()` Method:

```
Path leftToRight = new Path();
leftToRight.moveTo(0,0);
leftToRight.lineTo(200,200);

Path rightToLeft = new Path();
rightToLeft.moveTo(200,0);
rightToLeft.lineTo(0,200);

Path resultPath = new Path();

if (resultPath.op(rightToLeft, leftToRight, Path.Op.INTERSECT)) {
    if (!resultPath.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), "INTERSECTION DETECTED");
    } else {
        Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), "NO INTERSECTION DETECTED");
    }
}
```

The log output says 'NO INTERSECTION DETECTED'. I already read many answers around this topic on StackOverflow, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184397/path-intersection-in-android), but using Region.op is not an option in my case, as my tests showed that it will create a rectangle around the path before intersecting.

Some sources indicate that intersect might only properly work for Path objects that have a closed bound, like a square or a rectangle. But I can hardly imagine that Google would not implement basic line intersection. What am I missing here?

So I am thankful for a plain answer, whether it is possible to intersect Paths that just contain lines in Android using this method, or not.

Comment: I think there is a typo on your code..."leftToRight.moveTo(200,0);" refers to previous Path object and not the second one.

Comment: @emandt You're right, thanks, edited my post. Tried again with the corrected code, but still, the problem persists.

Comment: Op.INTERSECT, or more in general OP, works only on Closed paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time trying around, I found that the method `myPaint.getFillType(Path src, Path dst)` does the trick. What it actually does is it takes the Path `src` and will apply `myPaint` to it and store the result in `dst`. After the operation, Path `dst` drawn without any specific Paint will look the same as Path `src` drawn with `myPaint`.

As a side effect of this, `dst` will now no longer be a 'hairline' (aka width 0), where no intersection can be detected. It now will be a closed shape with a certain thickness. With that, Op.INTERSECTION does work.
The updated code looks like this:

```
Path leftToRight = new Path();
leftToRight.moveTo(0,0);
leftToRight.lineTo(200,200);

Path rightToLeft = new Path();
rightToLeft.moveTo(200,0);
rightToLeft.lineTo(0,200);

Paint myPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
myPaint.getFillPath(leftToRight, leftToRight);
myPaint.getFillPath(rightToLeft, rightToLeft);

Path resultPath = new Path();

if (resultPath.op(rightToLeft, leftToRight, Path.Op.INTERSECT)) {
    if (!resultPath.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e(this.getLocalClassName(), "INTERSECTION DETECTED :)");
    } else {
        Log.e(this.getLocalClassName(), "NO INTERSECTION DETECTED :(");
    }
}
```

Note that `setStrokeWidth()` obviously needs to be set to a value > 0.