# android line intersect with itself

Tags: android, line, draw

[image]

Hello friends,

I draw a line using **canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);** method.
but having some problem, i want to get whether line intersect with itself or not.
so please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: first of all it is not a line :)

Comment: ok its a path, which is draw on touch move.

Comment: You will be having all the points that you have drawn so on touchMove just check the new point is intersecting with any of these points

Comment: how do you populate your path ?

Answer (score 3):

For better performance and UI response create a separate Thread with a Handler and Looper. Also use a HashSet to store the path which tells you of an intersection when you add a position since add() returns a boolean.

Here is some code which should hopefully give better performance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private String position, lastPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Tracker t = new Tracker();
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mHandler != null) 
            mHandler.getLooper().quit();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            position = event.getX()+","+event.getY();
            if (position.equals(lastPosition)) break; 

            if (mHandler != null) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.obj = position;
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }

            lastPosition = position;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class Tracker extends Thread {
        HashSet<String> path = new HashSet<String>(); 

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            mHandler = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    String position = String.valueOf(msg.obj);
                    if (!path.add(position)) 
                        Log.w("Intersection", position);//Handle the intersection
                }
            };          
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

save the coordinates from events

```
    @Override
```

`public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {`
event.getX();event.getY()`

}

to a Hashmap and compare

Comment: Oh dear! This is a very bad answer that will cause some incandescent objects in this universe and any other universe, such as your sun and mine as well, to cease their emissions and, therefore, we will all be doomed. Use a Hashmap instead of an array!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're best bet would be to:

1) Keep one path representing what's currently on the canvas, and every time you use `canvas.drawPath(nextPath)`, also add it to your global path and do something like `globalPath.addPath(nextPath)`

2) Take a look at this post: [Collision detection with bitmaps on SurfaceView's canvas in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843578/collision-detection-with-bitmaps-on-surfaceviews-canvas-in-android/9918830#9918830). It seems that you should be able to compare the globalPath to the nextPath and tell if they ever collide.

3) If instead you wanted to just know if a single path collides with itself and don't care about adding new paths or anything, we'd need more information on how you're drawing this path. With lines, arcs, circles??